# How do I remove/add the pipe symbol (' | ') between links in a page/template_links block? (in XML, not links.phtml)

Tags: xml, magento

I'm working on organizing my footer into columns, and of course I'm working exclusively within local.xml, as all competent Magento developers aspire to do.

In local.xml, I've removed the original '**footer_links**' and '**cms_footer_links**' blocks that are instantiated in page.xml and cms.xml.  Then I reference 'footer' and instantiate two **page/template_links** blocks, assigning their templates to unique custom phtml files which are just copies of /theme/templates/page/template/links.phtml but named differently from each other (so that I can assign separate css classes to those blocks for later formatting).

The problem is that between the 3 links in the left column's page/template_links block, "footer_col_links_left", there is a pipe symbol (' | ').  And, after *both* of my two links created in my cms_footer_links2 cms/block block, there is that pipe symbol (strangely, even the last item has a trailing pipe, whereas this was not the case for the 3rd/last link in the template_links block mentioned above).

Where are these pipes coming from?  They are not explicitly echoed by any template files, and I do not believe that there is a default afterText being used because for the first link I went ahead and passed all possible parameters for the addLink action method, yet there was no change.

Here is the code:

```
<default>
    <remove name="footer_links"/>
    <remove name="cms_footer_links"/>

    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_col_links_left" as="footer_links_left" template="page/template/column_links_left.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addLink"><label>About Us</label><url>about-us</url><title>About Us</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/><position>1</position><liParams/><aParams/><beforeText/><afterText/></action>
            <action method="addLink" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
        </block>
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_col_links_mid" as="footer_links_mid" template="page/template/column_links_mid.phtml">
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links2">
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                Put Privacy Policy + Terms and Conditions here, call it "footer_links" in the backend
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="cms_payment_logos">
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                Put credit card and Geotrust SSL logos here, call it "payment_logos" in the backend                 
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>payment_logos</block_id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Also, there are no pipes between the header top.links, and I can't see what is different about them in XML.  Well ok, there is one thing that is different, and I don't understand how it works either, and that is how "top.links", the page/template_links block instantiated within page.xml, is not associated with a template file (there is no template="/page/block/template/links.php" like how "footer_links" was defined).  What's up with that?  Is there a default template associated to page/template_links blocks?  And if so, where is *that* designated?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know about your question out the top of my head but you can enable path hints for template files in the configuration > [select website OR store, setting wont show up otherwise] -> developer -> debug(not sure about this last one). If no hints are given for a particular block it may be that its awkwardly placed, try investigating the parent block and see what call gets the relevant childhtml for that block.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- there is no problem getting the blocks to render, I just want to know where the pipe symbols are coming from in page/template_links blocks (between every list item, and sometimes after all of them, but not always (which is another question)) so that I can remove them.  BTW, I don't think this is related, but fyi, apparently cms blocks legitimately do not show template hints for some reason (see the default footer_links block which is defined in cms.xml).

Comment: This may have been done in CSS...have you used something like Firebug to check out whether there is a pipe character there, or that it's actually in the HTML?

Comment: yeah.. I'm using Dreamweaver.  it sees the template_links blocks as "< inline style >" and the styling has nothing to suggest special treatment of list items, it shows only stuff like background, font, color,padding, margin, z-index, etc...   Here is an example demo site with the default footer:  http://demo5.magemojo.com/  Are you implying that you know that it is possible for unordered lists to have weird and uncommonly known attributes such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these pipes are set by css: in the demo link you gave, it's this line:

```
.footer li { display:inline; background:url(http://demo5.magemojo.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/bkg_pipe2.gif) 100% 60% no-repeat; padding:0 7px 0 4px; }
```

Comment: aha!  yes, thanks.. don't I feel stupid!  Apparently when you click on an element in DreamWeaver when not in Inspector mode, inline styles show up in the Rules panel instead of the underlying rules defined for that element in external css, so you have to use the Inspector to see it.  Just a quirk of the tool.  Oh well, hopefully my question can serve as a learning example for using the addLinks action method.  Thanks Dave

Comment: Hey you know what, this was all due to a dreamweaver bug after all.  I was messing around looking for my main-container class to see what the filename was my side shadows, and now *it* wouldn't appear in the inspector!  I closed DW and reopened, and now I can see all elements properly, including the original .footer li, in the rules list with the Inspector.  Ugh!  Can't wait for CS6..

Comment: I'd strongly recomend not to use DW for working with Magento. Give a try to eclipse or netbeans. Anyway, for this issue all I needed was firebug: if you don't use it, try it, it will revolutionize the way you do websites.

Comment: Thanks - I do find DW easy to work with for making edits, it's just this Inspector bug that I've reported at the Adobe forums a couple of times which causes problems.  DW also does help if you aren't familiar with all of the available CSS attributes (This is my first web development project ever, I used to be a hardware guy).  As for Firebug, I've had it installed for a while, but I only just yesterday realized that it has its own Inspector mode!  Excellent.  Now if it lets me easily make edits saved locally to easy to find css files, then I could use DW only when I need to know new attributes

Comment: btw I do have netbeans installed, thinking I was going to use it for javascript, but I did not know if I could use it to manage web development.  I may switch to it after I get this store up.  Thanks again